# foreach Statements with a function

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach

ok I am trying to answer a question and learning to code. regarding an array and using foreach statements the function must remain as this "function animalNames" must stay somewhere but apparently, I am doing something wrong because I get it returned as undefined. even through it produces the correct array back could someone look at it and let me know what i have done wrong.

attached is a picture of the code and array and question that i answered. this is how i wrote my function.

```js
     const displayNames = [];
    
    zooAnimals.forEach(function animalNames(element){
        
    var display = "name: " + element.animal_name + ", " + "scientific: " + element.scientific_name
       
     displayNames.push(display);
         
      })
      console.log(displayNames);
```

again i get the correct array back and the data looks correct...but animalNames comes back as undefined...i cannot remove this portion i am to keep it there but i do not know what to do with it.

[image: code/question and array]

Comment: can you please explain what is it that you want to achieve and which value is undefined ?

Comment: its a bit to write out, I took a picture of the question to try and show what i have done with the question.

Comment: most probably the animalNames is a predefined function, if not try the answer that I added

Comment: I did it just showed the new const as being undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this, it defines a function animalNames as separate function

```js
    const displayNames = [];
    const zooAnimals = [
     {animal_name:"Jackel",scientific_name:"Canine"}
    ]
    function animalNames({animal_name, scientific_name}){
      return `name: ${animal_name}, scientific: ${scientific_name}`
    }
    zooAnimals.forEach((element)=>{
     displayNames.push(animalNames(element));
    })
    console.log(displayNames);
```

Comment: Why put the array name as a constant? i did run that but then it tells me zooAnimals is undefined. should i be using a forEach(callbackFn)?

Comment: we are not reassigning it right

Comment: No we are not reassigning

Comment: then const will work

Comment: we are using a `forEach` here

Comment: correct we must use a foreach...i can write it out as it was in the picture and get back the answer in a new array with the correct results, but i guess i have undefined function or something.

Comment: which variable is undefined ?

Comment: in your screenshot, I can see `zooAnimals` as const and same with `displayNames`

Comment: in my original code i get "animalNames" as undefined in the code you provided i get "zooAnimals" as undefined.

Comment: are you defining `zooAnimals` in my code like I have declared

Comment: i just did a full copy and paste to ensure it is exactly as you put it and i am assuming i did something incorrectly but now i am getting that zooAnimals has already been declared?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are following [this challenge](https://github.com/bloominstituteoftechnology/web-sprint-challenge-javascript-fundamentals/blob/master/index.js). In this case, make sure to read the instructions properly:

> The zoos want to display both the scientific name and the animal name in front of the habitats.
> Use **animalNames to populate** and **return the displayNames array** with only the animal name and scientific name of each animal.
> displayNames will be an **array of strings**, and each string should follow this pattern: "name: {name}, scientific: {scientific name}"

So from the instructions you are expected to create a function `animalNames()` that creates an array named `displayNames` and returns this array from within your function `animalNames()`. The array `displayNames` contains strings of the sturcture `name: animal_name, scientific: scientific_name`.

```js
// you could set zooAnimals as a required parameter in your function 
// but as it is defined in the same file you can access it directly as well
function animalNames() {
    const displayNames = [];
    // you have to do the forEach on zooAnimals here
    zooAnimals.forEach(animal => displayNames.push(`name: ${animal.animal_name}, scientific: ${animal.scientific_name}`))
    // return an array
    return displayNames;
}
```

The way you did it, the function `animalsName()` is an anonymous function that only exists within the `zooAnimals.forEach()` call. Therefore, it is undefined.